# Why Word app constants are not usable in c++ builder

Tags: ms-office, c++builder

I'm using TWordApplication in c++ builder when I try this line of code

```
Table1->Rows->SetLeftIndent( 12.5, wdAdjustNone);
```

it gives me an error !!

```
[BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(46): E2451 Undefined symbol 'wdAdjustNone'
    Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(19): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *)
```

What else unit files do I need to include in my app???

Comment: I have added Word Object Lib 14 version!

Answer (score 0):

Check out in what header file wdAdjustNone is defined. Or maybe you have a typo in the name.